# Need help with a lemma explanation regarding triangle counting in graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Can you please explain this lemma? I read it in [this research paper](http://i11www.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/extra/publications/sw-fclt-05_t.pdf).[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a graph with 73 edges. Then it could be that you have a 12-vertex clique, that is, a set of 12 vertices, each adjacent to each of the others (that accounts for 66 edges), together with another 7 edges somewhere else. The 12-clique has 12-choose-3 triangles, which is $(12)(11)(10)/(1)(2)(3)$, which is close to $(1/6)(12)^3$. That's your $\Theta(n^3)$.

Now, the number of edges, $m=73$, is close to the number of edges in the 12-clique (66), which is close to half the square of 12. That is, $m=\Theta(n^2)$. Put these together, you get the number of triangles being $\Theta(m^{3/2})$.

Comment: I get the first part of your explanation but can't get the second part.

Comment: I'm sorry, you'll have to be more specific. You don't get that 73 is close to 66? Exactly what is it you can't get?

Comment: How you get to  That is, m=Θ(n2) and  Θ(m3/2). I understand the rest of your comments

Comment: $m=73$, the number of edges, is close to the square of $n$, the number of vertices in the clique, because a clique on $n$ verices has ... how many edges? So $m=\Theta(n^2)$. Now if $m=\Theta(n^2)$, and number of triangles is $\Theta(n^3)$, then you just eliminate $n$ to get number of triangles is $\Theta(m^{3/2})$.